# Cannot connect Charles Proxy to see traffic on any mobile

Tags: charles-proxy

First of, I can see on traffic coming through when I browse on my desktop.

I have set the IP in network settings along with the port but when I connect I do not get the do you want to connect this phone message from Charles.
I have:

- deleted all certificates and tried to go to chls.pro/ssl but get no internet message and the certificate doesn't download.
- tried ios and android both with the same result.
- tried to manually add it to the access devices in Charles.

The only difference is from two weeks ago when I last did this successfully is the VPN I am on (I open the Charles before connecting to the VPN, to rule that out).

Any suggestions? I am going crazy!

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues that can cause this issue: I collect here and you can verify each step to solve it: https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/my-ios-devices-couldnt-connect-to-proxyman-via-proxy

I would like to summarize:

1. Check if your Firewall is blocking all incoming traffic -> Turn it OFF
2. Stop all VPN app from your iOS device
3. Make sure your iOS devices and your macOS are in the same network.

Disclaimer: I create the Proxyman app, which is a modern version of Charles-Proxy. Hopefully it helps you resolve the problem.

Comment: "Stop all VPN" ... many thanks!